# How to open base64 PDF in Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, google-chrome-extension, base64

I have a simple Chrome application. There is a base64 string. In it, I store a PDF file and I want to open this PDF file on new `window` or `iframe`.

I tried to create an iframe with `src="data:application/pdf;base64,.."`.

After that, I get this error:

> Refused to load plugin data from
>   'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOfCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3R…Q4RUU5MzdDRDQyM0RFNEI4MTkzNDU3MzIzMTM2OQo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMjA0NTQKJSVFT0YK'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that
>   'object-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

Comment: App or extension? This is vitally important.

Comment: Besides, you say "new window or iframe" - have you tried a new tab with it?

Answer (score 5):

As [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) mentioned, try loading it as a new tab.

In a *web page*, you can do either

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,DATA', '_blank')
```

or (to load on same window)

```
window.location.href="data:application/pdf;base64,DATA"
```

Hope this helps. :/

Comment: If it's a Chrome App, then it may be problematic. Chrome Apps are [not allowed to interact with browser](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) this way.

Comment: So it might need something like a webview, or (upcoming) [`browser` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser). That said, the author **needs** to clarify if he means an app or an extension. Tags and question contradict each other.

Comment: Agreed. Also, now when I see my own answer, I too see that it's not really helpful in either context. :/

Answer (score -1):

try loading it as a new tab, then in the browser bar, you can paste this where "xxx" is equivalent to the base 64 code

```
data:application/pdf;base64,XXXX
```

Hope this helps too.